# Using the Google Places (new) API Text Search Function with specific addresses

Tags: kotlin, google-api

I am trying to use the Google Places (new) API to return a place based on a specific address. This is the body of the request:

```
  {
   "textQuery" : "$query",
    "locationBias": {
        "circle": {
            "center": {
                "latitude": 37,
                "longitude": -36
      },
            "radius": 50000
    }
  }
 }
```

If I pass in "Pizza" or "Pizza near me" I get an array of objects fitting that description within the specified location. One of those places is Papa Johns at 231 e mercury blvd. If I pass in 231 e mercury blvd I get a null value and an error from the log that says "Field 'places' is required for type with serial name 'com.example.surge_app.data.GooglePlacesList', but it was missing at path: $"

This indicates to me an issue with deserializing the JSON string into a Kotlin object. This is my Kotlin object:

```
    @Serializable
    data class DisplayName(
        val text: String,
        val languageCode: String
    )

    @Serializable
    data class Place(
        val formattedAddress: String,
        val displayName: DisplayName
    )

    @Serializable
    data class GooglePlacesList(
        val places: List<Place>
    )
```

I used the "Try It" feature in the API documentation, which can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/text-search?apix_params=%7B%22fields%22%3A%22places.displayName%2Cplaces.formattedAddress%2Cplaces.priceLevel%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%22textQuery%22%3A%2225%20long%20Bridge%20rd%22%2C%22priceLevels%22%3A%5B%22PRICE_LEVEL_INEXPENSIVE%22%2C%22PRICE_LEVEL_MODERATE%22%5D%2C%22locationBias%22%3A%7B%22circle%22%3A%7B%22center%22%3A%7B%22latitude%22%3A37%2C%22longitude%22%3A-36%7D%2C%22radius%22%3A50000%7D%7D%7D%7D#try-it). If you copy and paste my request body into the field at this link, replacing $query with either pizza or 231 e mercury blvd, I get the expected response. The response I get when typing in 231 e mercury blvd in my application is null and I am unsure why.

I have tried following the documentation as best I can and cannot find any thing wrong with what I am doing. I checked my gradle dependencies and everything is correct.